# Fastest way to parse big matrix into csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I have an array containing ~30k lines (arrays) of data.

I've tried:

```
@data.map(&:to_csv).join
```

And also

```
@data.each do |line_data|
  CSV.generate_line line_data
end
```

They both take around 8 seconds. Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: I doubt that there's a faster way, without more context. Can parts of it be pre-generated? What will it be used for?

Comment: This stringifying shouldn't take 8 seconds (unless your individual arrays are huge and/or your machine is terribly underpowered). Something else must be eating the time.

Comment: It's dumped into a view file (Ruby on Rails) which is then presented to the user to be downloaded. The data is collected from a db, and it just needs to be plain text in a csv format

Comment: If your data does not include fields that need to be escaped (strings that may include `,` or `"`) you can try to generate the csv using `@data.map { |row| row.join(',') }.join("\n")`

Comment: If it is a one-time task, 8 secs are perfectly good. If it is recurring, you should rethink the approach.